# How to extractvalue of table counts using xml in DB2? (see working Oracle equivalent)

Tags: xml, database, oracle, db2, database-administration

DBA experts, 
I am trying to list out some tables and that table's count using one query only in DB2.

I have been able to achieve this in Oracle by extracting value of the xml - see Oracle query below

```
select a.table_name, 
to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||a.table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count 
from all_tables a
where a.owner = user 
and a.table_name like 'E_AUD%';
```

The result looks like below

```
TABLE_NAME     COUNT
----------    ------
E_AUD_LOG     198001
E_AUD_LOG_1   435900
```

I am a little puzzled as to how I can write the extractvalue portion of the DB2 equivalent query - any pointers? I researched about DB2 xmls but it is not straight forward to me like Oracle was...

```
select s.name
--, to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||s.name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count 
from sysibm.systables s 
where s.creator = user
and s.type = 'T'
and s.name like 'E_AUD%';
```

Comment: Why cant you simply use "select name, card from sysibm.systables with ur"? What is the real need to be running a count(*) on all tables dynamically?

Comment: @askids This is for a purge process. The counts run before a purge begins and right after to the count of rows deleted. Needs to be dynamic